# Importing Offline Map Nutiteq From Open Street Map

Tags: android, openstreetmap, nutiteq

I am currently trying to import an offline map to nutiteq. 
I have downloaded a map from OpenStreetMap but that map has an .osm extension. 
How can I import that kind of extension to Android ?

Comment: MBTiles would be a good option to use maps in an offline mode.

Comment: and how to make the *.osm become MBTiles @PriyankaMinhas ? nutiteq tutorials seems very advanced for beginner users....

Comment: I have made mb tiles on my own using a software called Mobile Atlas creator. Hope it would help you too. Regarding the conversion of osm to mb tiles, i am not sure as i was unable to find a software related to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.osm` is just [OSM's XML file format](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) containing [elements](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) and [tags](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags). That is, it contains *raw* data. According to the [nutiteq website](http://www.nutiteq.com/) nutiteq doesn't support this format directly. But it supports various other formats like [MBTiles](https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/wiki/Offline-map-tiles) which are suitable for offline use.

Comment: which means.... nutiteq has a converter for that format to be readable @ChasingCars ?

Comment: Nutiteq SDK supports several formats really. For Mapsforge you should use mapsforge tool - .map file plugin for osmosis. For Nutiteq vector maps (coming with SDK 3.x) nutiteq will provide OSM conversion toolkit.

Answer (score 2):

As scai mentions, .osm is raw data file which cannot be directly used. .osm is data exchange format and it needs processing to be used in applications, including apps with Nutiteq SDK. Main missing piece from .osm file is visual styling: .osm file defines coordinates of objects and identity (e.g. that a line is "highway"), but it gives no hint whatsoever how to draw it - with which colors, line width etc.

What I'd suggest to try is to convert .osm file to .map file using osmosis, and then use mapsforge library to render a map [like shown in Nutiteq wiki page](https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/wiki/Mapsforge-layer). Mapsforge includes some default style, but you can find nicer stylesheets. There are several providers for readymade and up-to-date .map files with OpenStreetMap data, so maybe you do not need to do the conversion, one of them is [AndroidMaps](http://www.androidmaps.co.uk/) who even includes even several stylesheets.

Comment: you mean once we download the files from Androidmaps.co.uk we can directly set it as the offline source in Nutiteq code? @JaakL

Comment: @gumuruh - yes. For implementation sample see the wiki page mentioned in the answer above.